# apply jquery click event inside ng-include file

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onclick

I am developing an angularjs application where I have a header.html file which is included inside index.html file as `<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>` where header file include

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Link1.html">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="Link2.html">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

In index.html i have a jquery click action something as

```
 $('#logout').on('click', function (e) {          
            location.href = 'login.html';          
    });
```

But the click event is not working. Please guide me.

**EDIT:** My **header.html file** as follows:

```
 <nav>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Link1.html">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="Link2.html">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

**index.html file**:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

      <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>

      <!-- my index page content goes here which is built using angularjs logic -->

      <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>

    </div>
    <script src="call/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/logout.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', []);
      app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $q, $http) {
        // my angularjs logics...
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**logout.js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#logout').on('click', function(e) {
   if(somecondition)
    location.href = 'login.html';
   else
        alert('Oops something went wrong!');
  });
});
```

Also i have two other files `link1.html` and `link2.html`

Comment: write jquery function on header.html or alternatively you may share the code for index.html

Comment: it does not work because the `logout` link is not yet present by the time the `.on` method is called

Comment: Please see the edit with detail code

Answer (score 0):

simplest thing would be:

```
<li><a href="index.html" id="logout">Logout</a></li>
```

And as you are having an angular application, you might do this with your route configuations as well:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Link1">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Link2">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/index" id="logout">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/index', {
        templateUrl : 'path/index.html',
        controller  : 'homeCtrl'
    })
    ...other routes
    .otherwise({redirect:'/index'})
```